# Libgdx Get Font Height with a Wrap

Tags: java, libgdx, fonts

is possible to get the 'Height' of a font drawed with the drawWrapped methods (with a wrapWidth) ?

getMultiLineBounds only works when **\n** is used, but when drawing with drawWrapped it doesn't give the right Height.

**Text**

```
String text = "hello this is very lonnnnng text without new line";
float wrapWidth = 100;
```

**Display code** :

```
 font.drawWrapped(batch, text, x, y, wrapWidth, alignment);
```

My '**get the displayed height code**' :

```
 font.getMultiLineBounds(text).height;
```

**Output** :

```
 hello this is very
 lonnnnng text without
 new line
```

**Problem** :

How to have the total height of the displayed text by the methods : DrawWrapped

Can you help me please ? thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [getWrappedBounds](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#getWrappedBounds%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20float%29) instead of getMultiLineBounds

Comment: My BitmapFont class does not contain this method - any ideas?